# How to fix Docker Permission deined

Tags: docker, permissions, ubuntu-20.04

After installing docker on ubuntu 20.04 and pulling official ubuntu docker image I run imgae with this response

```
martin@martin-Dell-Ubuntu:~$ docker run -ti ubuntu
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
root@32f7fd74eb1b:/#
```

docker group is created :

```
martin@martin-Dell-Ubuntu:~$ groups
martin adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker
```

user(martin) is in docker group:

```
martin@martin-Dell-Ubuntu:~$ groups martin
martin : martin adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker
```